# VBA code to hide userform-specified list of rows on multiple sheets stopped working

Tags: vba, excel

My timekeeping workbook has 52 sheets, each containing data for one week of the year.  Cell `A16` on each sheet has the Sunday that starts the week off.  (i.e. on Sheet "Jun 15", `A16` = "Jun 11", stored as a date (6/11/2017))

Sometimes, I need to show or hide rows from this date forward.  For instance, maybe row 22 was useful for me up until this week, but it won't be for the rest of the year, so I want to hide it from Jun 11 onward.

I wrote code that opens a userform, accepts a comma separated list, and for any numerical values, hides those rows.

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim firstDate As Double
Dim hidelistEntry As Variant
hidelistEntry = InputBox("Enter list of rows to HIDE from this sheet forward. (Comma Separated)")

hidelist = Split(hidelistEntry, ",") 'Turn input into an array of values.
firstDate = ActiveSheet.Range("a16").Value

    For Each WS In Worksheets
        If firstDate <= WS.Range("A16").Value Then  
           For Each hiderow In hidelist
              If IsNumeric(hiderow) Then  'Check to see if each item is a number
                  WS.Rows(Int(hiderow)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
               End If  '*****************See comment below
           Next
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

This code has been working great for me all year - until today.  It now hides the first row in the list, on the first page, then it throws up a "Code execution has been interrupted" error, and debugging takes me to the line marked with asterisks above.  Basically, it is not successfully iterating to the second numeric item in hideList, or cleanly exiting if there isn't one.  (If I enter *"dog, cat, 12, 13"*, it will correctly ignore *dog* and *cat*, hide *12*, then fail to move on to *13*)

Can anyone see what went wrong, or suggest how I can find this bug?  This had been working fine for months, and as far as I know, nothing should have changed.  I am stumped.

In case it is informative, here are sample locals after the error:
[image]

#### EDIT:   I RESTARTED MY COMPUTER AND NOW IT IS WORKING AS BEFORE.

Comment: Should I delete this question?  The solution does not seem to have been VBA related.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the line that is causing the problem, run it (which of course means it's not going to do anything) and then put the line back in, and recompile it. That's worked for me in the past.